# How to rewrite links on a page served by nginx using proxy pass

Tags: nginx

I need to make a configuration on nginx which when someone goes to https://domain1.com/plss/sub the server proxies the request to https://sub.domain2.com/.

My problem is the page being served contains links and anchors to external files/pages and thus i need to change their urls too to follow the rules of my proxy server. I tried to use sub_filter but it is not modifying anything in the content being served to the client.

My .conf file contains:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        server_name 192.168.110.136;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.key;

        location ~*/plss/(?<subdomain>[^/]+)/(?<path>.*)$ {
                resolver 8.8.8.8;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;

                sub_filter_once off;
                sub_filter_types *;
                sub_filter '="/' '="https://192.168.110.136/plss/$subdomain/';

                proxy_pass https://$subdomain.domain2.com/$path;
       }
}
```

For example in the head tag `<link rel="preload" as="style" href="/_next/static/css/fae7fa9d19554c8d.css">` should be changed to `<link rel="preload" as="style" href="https://192.168.110.136/plss/sub/_next/static/css/fae7fa9d19554c8d.css">` but all the links are served as they are without being changed.